# Original object is changed after cloning it

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I want to clone an object and then change it, however when I do that the original object is changed also:

```
let items = result.Project.ItemGroup[1].Build;
let newItem = { ...items[0] };
newItem.$.Include = `test`;
```

After I make an assignment on `newItem` object, the `items[0]` value is changed also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spread only makes a **shallow** copy. You're not changing what you copied, you're changing the object on its `$` property, which you didn't copy. `items[0].$` and `newItem.$` both refer to the **same** object:

```js
const items = [
  {
    $: {
      Include: "test"
    }
  }
];
let newItem = {...items[0]};
console.log(items[0].$ === newItem.$); // true
```

You'd need something like this to *also* clone the `$` object:

```
let newItem = {...items[0], $: {...items[0].$}};
```

```js
const items = [
  {
    $: {
      Include: "test"
    }
  }
];
let newItem = {...items[0], $: {...items[0].$}};
console.log(items[0].$ === newItem.$); // false
newItem.$.Include = "updated";
console.log(items[0].$.Include);       // "test"
console.log(newItem.$.Include);        // "updated"
```

(Or a [general deep-clone function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript).)